# how to make countable field depending on repeated values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to make new field with if condition to calculate values for same serial numbers as shown on the above pic.[image]

Comment: bring more clarity to your question.

Comment: what is your data and what is your desired result.

Comment: its a view collecting data from several tables, for example serial number 4 have values like 1000,1000,2000, i want to collect it in a new field to sum all three values to be 4000

Comment: SELECT serial_number,SUM(values )  FROM YOUR-VIEW GROUP BY serial_number

Comment: if i group the by serial it will not give me all the data, it will group it in one row.

Comment: SELECT serial_number,SUM(values ) OVER(PARTITION BY serial_number)  FROM YOUR-VIEW

Comment: [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ee827061e0e41ec36e349b862d34618)